# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "my_bundle_name"

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, bundle

I know this post is popular in here, there are a lot of questions about this problem, but nothing helped me to solve my problem. I have to ask this.

I created a bundle named "ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle".

I want to get users parameters from app/config.yml; This is my configuration parameters, i'm loading parameters from app/parameters.yml.

```
atl15_google_analytics:
    client_id:  "%ga_client_id%"
    client_secret: "%ga_client_secret%"
    developer_key: "%ga_developer_key%"
    redirect_uri: "%ga_redirect_uri%"
```

I did everything i read from symfony documentation book and the web. Nothing helped me at all...

This is my `DependencyInjection/Configuration.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace ATL15\GoogleAnalyticsBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder,
    Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('atl15_google_analytics');

        $rootNode->children()
                    ->scalarNode('client_id')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('client_secret')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('developer_key')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('redirect_uri')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                 ->end();

        //var_dump($rootNode); die;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And this is my `DependencyInjection/ATL15GoogleAnalyticsBundleExtension.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace ATL15\GoogleAnalyticsBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class ATL15GoogleAnalyticsExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

        foreach (array('config') as $basename) {
            $loader->load(sprintf('%s.yml', $basename));
        }

        foreach (array('client_id', 'client_secret', 'developer_key', 'redirect_uri') as $attribute) {
            $container->setParameter($attribute, $config[$attribute]);
        }
    }

    public function getAlias()
    {
        return 'atl15_google_analytics';
    }
}
```

And yes, i loaded this bundle from `app/AppKernel.php`;

```
    new ATL15\GoogleAnalyticsBundle\ATL15GoogleAnalyticsBundle(),
```

Everytime i'm getting this error:

> [Sat Sep 14 17:37:24 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:
>   Uncaught exception
>   'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException'
>   with message 'There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "atl15_google_analytics" (in
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/src/ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "atl15_google_analytics", found none' in
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php:290\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(260):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->validate(Array,
>   '/var/www/vsy-bi...')\n#1
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(44):
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->loadFile('/var/www/vsy-bi...')\n#2
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/src/ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle/DependencyInjection/ATL15GoogleAnalyticsExtension.php(28):
>   Symfon in
>   /var/www/vsy-bio/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php
>   on line 290

Could you please help me?

Comment: Looks like a typo. Try renaming *"ATL15GoogleAnalyticsBundleExtension.php"* to *"ATL15GoogleAnalyticsExtension.php"*

Comment: Sorry my fault, the correct name is ATL15GoogleAnalyticsExtension.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your `ATL15GoogleAnalyticsExtension` and your error it looks like you are loading a file called `config.yml` from your bundles Resources\config which is using the parameters stated in the `app\config\config.yml`.

The file `ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml` should only contain the 2 namespace `parameters` and `services` like...

```
parameters:
    atl15_google_analytics.something.class: ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle...

services:
    atl15_google_analytics.something.services:
        class: %atl15_google_analytics.something.class%
```

The config data is passed in to the Extension file by `$config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);` rather than you needing to call the file itself so you don't need to load the `Resources/config/config.yml` unless that actually contains any internal services or parameters for your bundle.

Comment: There will be no default data for parameters in config file. Users should define their values in app/config.yml. There will be only required parameters in my bundle's config.yml.

Comment: Is your `Resources/config/config.yml` laid out as above or similar to that of the `app/config/config.yml` with your bundle alias as the namespace?

Comment: When i copy inside of my app/config/config.yml without values just typing "", then i get this error. It's empty now.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. `app/config/config.yml` should have all of your symfony settings like https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/config.yml . If it's empty then you would be having other issues like no db connection parameters or framework settings.

Comment: My bad. It's not `app/config/config.yml` it's bundle's config.yml. It's empty bro. Sorry.

Comment: The only way I have been to replicate your problem is by putting the wrong namespace in the `Resources/config/config.yml`. Have you tried clearing the cache lately? That's pretty much all I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

There is a foreach that is redundant:

```
foreach (array('config') as $basename) {
    $loader->load(sprintf('%s.yml', $basename));
}
```

Unless you have a config.yml file in your bundle's Resources folder, and you know what you are doing, remove this foreach. The line numbers in the stacktrace that you provided don't match up with your source code, so I guess you edited it afterwards, but I think the error is coming from this config.yml file.

You do not have to call $loader->load(), in order to read the parameters from app/config.yml, it is done automatically.

Answer (score -1):

The error is the name of the Extension class file and also the class name it needs to match the bundle:

should be GoogleAnalyticsExtension instead of ATL15GoogleAnalyticsBundleExtension, the file name needs to be GoogleAnalyticsExtension.php, and change atl15_google_analytics to google_analytics

Comment: This is [incorrect](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/src/Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeDemoExtension.php). The demo Bundle is called `AcmeDemoExtension` not `DemoExtension`

Comment: the bundle name is GoogleAnalytics not ATL15GoogleAnalytics, i named everything after the bundle, works for me
`I created a bundle named "ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle".`

Comment: Try running `php app/console -n generate:bundle --namespace="ATL15/GoogleAnalyticsBundle"`. The generated DependencyInjection folder is named `ATL15GoogleAnalyticsExtension`

Comment: sorry i see your point, well that worked for me i tried it out.

Comment: i think it could be something with the namespace, since he's got it all caps, i think that could be the issue. I believe my suggestion would work, removing the namespace name from the bundle name and other class names.

Comment: Bundle name is: ATL15GoogleAnalyticsBundle. Sorry for chaos.